# Module multiple registration

Tags: 7, users

Sorry, but I can not understand how I can make 2 different registration on 2 different pages - I installed and Profile2 Registration Pathom and Profile2 but on 2 different pages it displays the same fields of registration - I did 2 different Profile type but they same registration - help guys.

Comment: don't post login information in public forums. bots or malicious individuals could destroy your site

Comment: Try this patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1593230). It restricts profile types per role. Maybe that will help.